# Facebook Unity SDK (Android) - FB.Feed white screen

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've trawled t'interweb trying to see how to get around my issue but have not found anything yet.

I am using Unity 4.3.4, Facebook SDK 5.0.4 (I have tried the last three versions too), and have what I believe to be the latest versions of JDE, JDK and OpenSSL.

In my android game I can log in fine both on an Adnroid device and the Unity Editor (using an accesskey in the Editor), but when I try to Share using FB.Feed I get a blank Facebook screen on my device - in the Editor I get the activity as expected and can post to my timeline.

I have read that the hash key generated can be misleading, but getting the correct key fixed my previous issue around actually logging in so I doubt it is that.  The only other thing I think it could be is the Class Name?  This part leaves me stumped as I'm not sure what this should be and if setting the class name in the Facebook app settings makes any difference?

It may be some settings in Facebook apps that are causing this I suppose?

Does anybody have any ideas on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by one of the parameters you pass to FB.Feed. I had the same problem with FB.Feed working in the unity editor and on iOS but giving me a white screen on Android. Shortening the Feed Picture URL solved the problem.